# multiprocessing python map

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, multiprocessing

i have this task as function for the map function

```
def task(datetime):

    open_bool=False
    with suppress(Exception):
        offen_bool=IEX.open_at_time(offen_IEX,str(datetime), only_rth = True)
        if open_bool:
            return offen_bool
```

and this main function

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    df=getTable()

    with Pool(10) as pool:
        print("pool Start")    
        data=pool.map(task,enumerate(df["Time"]))
```

I don't want to get the whole array with the length of the initial dataframe length.

I need a function that works like map but gives me just the data in the return statement.

This multiprocessing thing is new to me, so I need a simple solution. In fact, I am glad that this just works.

Comment: The `return` statement returns `offen_bool` if `open_bool` is `True`, otherwise `None`. (I don't see how `open_bool` can be anything but `False`).  Do you mean that you do not want the `None` entries in the list returned by `pool.map`? Also, see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: it can return true, and yes i dont want the None oder False entries, in fact i want the index if its true, so i only get an array which has just the true values as indexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you are passing as the *iterable* to `pool.map` the expression `enumerate(df["Time"])`, then the actual argument to the worker function `task` will be a tuple consisting an index and a datetime value. So you should could declare the argument of `work` to be a tuple and unpack it:

```py
def task(tpl):
    index, datetime = tpl
    ...
```

Alternatively, use method `multiprocessing.Pool.starmap` as is being done below. You should then arrange for `work` to always return a tuple consisting of the passed index and either `True` or `False` according to whether it is an index you wish to have in your final result. For example:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool
import pandas as pd

def task(index, datetime):
    """
    open_bool=False
    with suppress(Exception):
        offen_bool=IEX.open_at_time(offen_IEX,str(datetime), only_rth = True)
        if open_bool:
            return offen_bool
    """
    # For demo purposes, we are only interested in odd datetime values
    # Return a tuple: (index, True/False value)
    return index, datetime % 2 == 1

if __name__ == '__main__':

    #df=getTable()
    df = pd.DataFrame({'Time': [9, 8, 16, 10, 31, 1]})

    with Pool(10) as pool:
        print("pool Start")
        true_indices = list(
            tpl[0] for tpl in pool.starmap(task, enumerate(df["Time"]))
            if tpl[1]
            )
        print(true_indices)
```

Prints:

```
pool Start
[0, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Did this resolve your issue? Feedback is appreciated.